# Create Array of Dictionaries iOS Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am trying to implement an array of dictionaries but I get an output different from my expectation.

In the following code snippet I create an array, a dictionary and execute the append operation:

```
var MemberArray = [[String: Any]]()

let dict = ["member_status":"1", 
            "member_id": memid ,
            "membership_number": memshpid, 
            "name": memname, 
            "mobile":memno ,
            "billing":"1"] as NSDictionary

MemberArray.append(dict as! [String : Any])
```

I need it to be this:

```
[
  {
"member_status": 1,
"member_id": 3,
"membership_number": "GI99010286",
"name": "Thomas",
"mobile": "9873684678",
"billing": 0
  },
  {
"member_status": 1,
"member_id": 5,
"membership_number": "GI99010144",
"name": "Raj",
"mobile": "9873684678",
"billing": 1
  }
]
```

But I get the following:

```
[
  [
"member_status": 1,
"member_id": 3,
"membership_number": "GI99010286",
"name": "Thomas",
"mobile": "9873684678",
"billing": 0
 ],
 [
"member_status": 1,
"member_id": 5,
"membership_number": "GI99010144",
"name": "Raj",
"mobile": "9873684678",
"billing": 1
  ]]
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: You need it in JSON format?

Comment: You are getting the correct behavior, in the latter print you have an array of dictionaries, but in your first print example you have the array of dictionaries in JSON format

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yes JSON Format

Comment: you have the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that you have to serialize that array. Here data is that array :

```
let dataSet = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
let jsonString = NSString(data: dataSet, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSString` in Swift? You should use `String`, since you aren't exploiting any functionality of `NSString` that `String` doesn't have, in which case you should stick to the native Swift type.

Comment: You can use string , changed this NSString to string                                                                                                                  
let jsonString = String(data: dataSet, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!